# jq get values from complex object

Tags: json, select, key, jq

I have an object that looks like this

```
{
  "my_list": [
    {
      "name": "an_image",
      "image": "an_image.com"
    },
    {
      "name": "another_image",
      "image": "another_image.com"
    },
  ...<more objects with image property>
  ],
  "foo": {
    "image": "foobar.io"
  },
  "bar": {
    "image": "bar_image.io"
  },
  ...<more objects with image property>
}
```

I'd like to get all of the image properties from each of the objects, and from each object in `my_list` and other lists that have objects that include an `image` property. So in this example I'd like to get

```
"an_image.com"
"another_image.com"
"foobar.io"
"bar_image.io"
```

We don't know the keys of any of these objects at runtime, so we can't reference `my_list`, `foo`, or `bar` in this example.

Previously we didn't have `my_list` in the object and `jq '.[].image'` worked, but now that results in `jq: error (at bar.json:18): Cannot index array with string "image"`.

The problem is that we don't know the name of the objects that contain `image` properties so we can't reference them explicitly, and now that we've added another element that's a list we're running into type errors, that I'm not sure how to solve.

I've tried various combinations of `.[].image`, but they all seem to run into issues with typing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't mind the terseness, you could perhaps go with:

```
jq '..|select(.image?).image'
```

Answer (score 1):

You could select by `objects` and items of `arrays`:

```bash
jq '.[] | ., arrays[] | objects.image'
```

```json
"an_image.com"
"another_image.com"
"foobar.io"
"bar_image.io"
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/mgGYjYbCclq)

Answer (score 0):

Using *recursive descent* `..` is more elegant:

```
jq '.. | .image? // empty'
```

Answer (score 0):

If the input is large, you might want to consider streaming the data in:

```bash
$ jq --stream -r 'select(.[0][-1] == "image")[1] // empty' input.json
an_image.com
another_image.com
foobar.io
bar_image.io
```

When streamed, your input will be processed as path/value pairs for the most part. Filter the paths you want, then return the value.